# Regular Expression for date format

Tags: regex

I want regex for this date format
    **Wed Jul 16 00:00:00 UTC 2008**.

Comment: Please use the utility in your language to read date.

Comment: 1. Why do you need a **regex** for that? 2. What have you tried?

Comment: First you need to try something and if you stuck some where then post a question for suggestion. SO users will provide you with most best suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<WeekDay>\w+)\s+(?<Month>\w+)\s+(?<MonthDay>\d+)\s+(?<Hour>\d+):(?<Min>\d+):(?<Sec>\d+)\s+(?<TimeZone>\w+)\s+(?<Year>\d+)
```

and get this groups

```
${WeekDay}
${Month}
${MonthDay}
${Hour}
${Min}
${Sec}
${TimeZone}
${Year}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex
`([a-zA-Z]{3}\s){2}\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sUTC\s\d{4}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = "Wed Jul 16 00:00:00 UTC 2008   Tue Jul 12 15:00:04 UTC 2009";
$pattern = '![a-zA-Z]{3}\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{2}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{4}!';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Wed Jul 16 00:00:00 UTC 2008 [1] => Tue Jul 12 15:00:04 UTC 2009 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

If you use `Java` with `SimpleDateFormat`